# Parsing nested JSON with list comprehension in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, list-comprehension

My data is as following (this just extract but there are much more objects, some don't have the `additionalData`)

```
{
   "referenceSetCount":1,
   "totalRowCount":4,
   "referenceSets":[
      {
         "name":"table",
         "rowCount":4,
         "_links":{
            "self":{
               "href":"link"
            }
         },
         "referenceDataItems":[
            {
               "col1":"5524",
               "col2":"yyy",
               "col3":1,
               "additionalData":[
                  {
                     "col1":111,
                     "col2":"xxxx",
                     "col3":1,
                     "col4":"18"
                  },
                  {
                     "col1":222,
                     "col2":"2222",
                     "col3":1,
                     "col4":"1"
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "col1":"26434",
               "col2":"dfdshere",
               "col3":2,
               "additionalData":[
                  {
                     "col1":34522,
                     "col2":"fsfs",
                     "col3":2,
                     "col4":"18"
                  },
                  {
                     "col1":5444,
                     "col2":"gregrege",
                     "col3":2,
                     "col4":"2"
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I'm trying to iterate with list comprehension to get dataframe of `referenceDataItems` and everything within that key, also `additionalData` if appears.

```
import os
import sys
import pandas as pd
import urllib.request, json

api_url = urllib.request.urlopen("link_to_my_data")

api_data = json.loads(api_url.read())

#nest loop to get referenceSets + nested additionalData
data_alt = [v for k, v in api_data.items() if k == 'referenceSets']
```

Expected result:

```
col1    col2        col3    col1    col2    col3    col4    col1    col2        col3    col4
5524    yyy         1       111     xxxx    1       18      222     2222        1       1
26434   dfdshere    2       34522   fsfs    2       18      5444    gregrege    2       2
```

Comment: You don't need a list comprehension. Just `api_data['referenceSets']`

Comment: terminology nitpick, but this isn't JSON. JSON is the text-based serialization format. You've *deserialized your JSON* into a Python data structure.

Comment: @Barmar - thank you but I have multpile `referenceSets`. `api_data['referenceSets']` will still require a loop to go through every single instance like: `api_data['referenceSets'][i][referenceDataItems]`

Comment: `api_data['referenceSets']` returns the list of all the reference sets, including everything in them.

Comment: If you want something specific from each reference set, you could use `names = [s['name'] for s in data_alt]`

Comment: You haven't shown what you want the result to be.

Comment: I added expected resultset @Barmar. I meant that I need all data from `referenceDataItems`.

Comment: I don't use pandas. Can you really have multiple columns with the same name?

Comment: Yes, this is expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some research and this almost got my desired data, needs little modification in `COLUMNS_TO_DROP`

```
COLUMNS_TO_DROP = ["additionalData"]

def expand_additional_data(items):
    for item in items:
        for av in item.get("additionalData", []):
            item[av["col2a"]] = av["col4a"]
        yield item


for ref_set in data["referenceSets"]:
    table_name = ref_set["name"]
    expanded = expand_additional_data(ref_set["referenceDataItems"])
    df = pd.DataFrame(expanded)
    df = df.drop(COLUMNS_TO_DROP, axis=1, errors="ignore")
    print(df)
```